# Replacing bedding and underwear for hygienic reasons

Tags: hygiene, clothes

[Many](https://www.nbcnews.com/better/pop-culture/here-s-how-often-you-should-replace-everything-your-bedroom-ncna844686) [sites](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/4890444/throw-underwear-and-knickers-away-after-a-year-to-be-more-hygienic/) [claim](https://www.goodhousekeeping.co.uk/institute/household-advice/cleaning-tips/this-is-how-often-you-should-wash-your-essentials) that bedding and underwear should be **thrown away** for sanitary reasons every few years (the exact recommendation varies between sites and clothing/bedding type).

This, regardless of the laundry routine they endure. So for example, even if you wash your underwear at 60°C with bleach every day, they should allegedly be [thrown in the garbage every year](http://www.bodyandsoul.com.au/health/health-advice/how-often-do-you-need-new-undies/news-story/8d8f1f64148cd18df733d7327f8cea34) for sanitary reasons.

How does this make sense? Why does the item's age matter? Isn't a 5-year old item (pillow/underwear/duvet/etc) as good as new, hygienically speaking, after being washed with a detergent at 60°C? Do you mean to tell me things get "too contaminated" over time, to the point where they are a "sanitary lost cause" and must be thrown away and replaced?

Note that I'm only talking about the hygienic perspective. For the sake of this discussion let's ignore things like loss of functionality, comfort, aesthetics, etc.

Comment: I love it when articles throw out scary sounding numbers like how many bacteria can be found in clean underwear. Seriously, we live in a world immersed in bacteria. We eat them, drink them, breath them, and grow them in and on our bodies by the **billions**. 10K bacteria in your shorts is absolutely nothing compared to the number that are living on the skin covered by those shorts.

Comment: @CareyGregory That's such an important point: since Koch/Pasteur we developed a public discourse that is germophobe. We can't and shouldn't sterelize the world or our own bodies. There is such a huge gap. –– Have you had the number of germs counted on your keyboard lately; on phones it's even worse…

Comment: Which is why milk is pasteurised and not sterilised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments in that article.  It's rubbish.

Does the NHS toss their bedding every few years??

To get rid of dust mites

> Wash bedding weekly. Wash all sheets, blankets, pillowcases and bedcovers in hot water that is at least 130 F (54.4 C) to kill dust mites and remove allergens. If bedding can't be washed hot, put the items in the dryer for at least 15 minutes at a temperature above 130 F (54.4 C) to kill the mites. Then wash and dry the bedding to remove allergens. Freezing nonwashable items for 24 hours also can kill dust mites, but this won't remove the allergens.

https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/dust-mites/diagnosis-treatment/drc-20352178

The sun newspaper is not a reliable source of health information.

Comment: A sidenote while this seems more a fit to lifehacks?: This whole thought needs to start at buying garments that can withstand >/=60°C If anyone buys a fabric that says "do not increase temperature above 30°C" then it this is a one-time throw-away garment, if no other ways of decontamination/disinfection are applicable!

Comment: @LangLangC I tend to ignore such instructions and wash at 60°C anyway. I guess I take a risk, but like you said it beats the alternative.

Comment: Thank you Graham, upvoted. While the Sun may not be a reliable source of information, there are many sites making similar claims (for example NBC, dailymail.co.uk, Wales Online etc). The main source seems to be the "Good Housekeeping Institute" (specifically https://www.goodhousekeeping.co.uk/institute/household-advice/cleaning-tips/this-is-how-often-you-should-wash-your-essentials). Some experts are cited as well, for example yearly underwear replacement is attributed in some sites to Dr Lisa Ackerley visiting Professor of Environmental Health, University of Salford.

Comment: I think people have just too much time on their hands and have to justify their existence hence these recommendations which go against common sense.

Comment: Fair enough. One more thing, would you agree with their washing recommendations? Towels and nightwear every 3 days, sheets every week, pillows and duvets twice a year, tea towels every day?

Comment: Realistically unless they can provide any data to support these suggestions I'd just ignore them.  When I was a lot younger I doubt I'd ever wash my sheets, or night attire .. since I was showering anyway in the morning.  And there's good reason not to wash at all! But that's another topic altogether.

Comment: Understood. I'll try and see which of these recommendations are backed up by actual data and/or experts. BTW I don't get notifications unless you start your comments with @OhadSchneider.

Comment: @OhadSchneider I predict you'll find that none of them are backed by credible data showing actual effects on health. It's pseudo-science being used as fodder to fill magazine and newspaper articles, and I wouldn't be at all surprised to find advertisements for bedding and/or underwear in those same issues.

Comment: I agree. I have extensive experience in infection control QI, and I cannot postulate a legitimate mechanism requiring disposal of household linens or clothing that can be washed with detergent - especially on hot.  My only addition is regarding washing bedding: besides the recommendations from medical societies (AAAAI, AAD, AAFP), both from patients' reports and personally, I have found that washing bed sheets weekly-ish on hot often improves allergic rhinitis/asthma symptoms (as part of allergen reduction methods).

Comment: @CareyGregory so basically you're saying that they might cite a microbiologist who would say there are such and such bacteria on towels and whatnot, but that won't prove the article's corollary of an *actual health risk*, right?

Comment: @DoctorWhom regarding bedding, I'm using dust mite protectors, would that change anything (like buy me more time between laundries)?

Comment: @OhadSchneider Yes, exactly. Finding bacteria means nothing in and of itself. Your skin hosts approximately 50 million bacteria per square inch. How much do you think it's going to matter if your shorts add a few thousand more?